# How do i implement a play again feature?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I would like to be prompted when the game finishes;
If I would like to play again.
And with a Y/N input: either exiting the game or repeat it.

How do I go about this in the most efficient way?

EDIT: Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method playAgain() is undefined for the type Main   Main.java   /ScaredyCat/src/se/gruppfisk/scaredycat/main    line 12 Java Problem

```
public boolean playAgain(Scanner keyboard) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (Y/N): ");
        String reply = keyboard.nextLine();
        return reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
    } finally {
        keyboard.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a loop to your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        ScaredyCat game = new ScaredyCat(new Player("Urkel",23),new Player("Steve", 18));
        game.play();
    } while(playAgain());
}

private static boolean playAgain() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N): ");
    String replay = keyboard.nextLine();
    return replay.equals("Y");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
If you were to do it with a separate method. Like the half assed example i gave in the edited description. Would it be possible to make the playAgain method to execute after a certain line or when System.out.printf("%s is the winner!" occurs?

Comment: @eximp yeah you could do it like that. That's actually a good idea. See my edit. I didn't test it but it should work. Also, please remember to upvote / accept =]

Comment: Don't leave you `Scanner keyboard` like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please note, stream or reader should be closed in the same scope/module, it is created in. In your case, `Scanner` should not be closed inside `playAgain()` because, it is an input parameter to the API.

A loop can be implemented to check if user wants to play again or not. Generally `do-while` loop is used because it will run once before checking the condition. Using other loops will need a variable which is by default `true`.

**Solution using `do-while`:**

```
boolean playAgain = false;
do{
  Game game = new Game();
  game.play();      
  playAgain = ScaredyCat.playAgain();
}while(playAgain);
```

**Solution using `while`:**

```
boolean playAgain = true;
while(playAgain){
  Game game = new Game();
  game.play();      
  playAgain = ScaredyCat.playAgain();
}
```

**Add following in `ScaredyCat.java`**

```
public static boolean playAgain() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N): ");
    String replay = keyboard.nextLine();
    return replay.equals("Y");  //or equalsIgnoreCase
}
```

The exception you mentioned in edit section means that `playAgain()` method is not available in your `Main.java` file. Also, if you are using this method from within `main(String[])` method, it must be `static` and if `non-static`, it must belong to some object and must be called by object reference. Method suggested by [nhouser9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6147506/nhouser9) should work.

Comment: It won't work in Main whatever I do.
I'd prefer it outside Main if possible.
Thanks!

Comment: @eximp Why wouldn't it work in Main.java. It is an independent feature than game.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method playAgain() is undefined for the type Main Main.java /ScaredyCat/src/se/gruppfisk/scaredycat/main line 13 Java Problem

EDIT: i mean outside Main. My bad.


Line 13: playAgain = playAgain();

Comment: Where do you want want `playAgain()`...inside `Main.java` or some other file? Both can be done easily.

Comment: I would like it in another file. ScaredyCat